# Can an X video driver be restarted/reinitialized without losing the session?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, lxde

Have been experiencing problems with my laptop display usually brought on by interacting with graphics images in chromium web browser. When it happens the display goes haywire as if the horizontal and vertical sync had been messed with on an old CRT monitor, while I can still see the image its interlaced, rolling all over the place and completely unusable requiring a hard reset.

Is there any way to reset the video without losing everything that was currently active on the desktop?

[I'm using the LXLE distro which includes the LXDE desktop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases switching virtual consoles will work. sometimes you may be able to ssh in and reset the video card but It has been a long time since I have done this. In some cases using vnc will allow you to preserve your session across a x server restart, but it won't help if you have to reboot. but other than that ...

no, not realy